# How can I capture the exit status of `nc` when run from `timeout`?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, netcat

I want to test connectivity to an arbitrary host using netcat. It seems the `-w` argument does not actually close the connection after 5 seconds. (This is on Ubuntu 14.04 and `netcat-traditional` 1.10-40). It will only continue to try connecting for 5 seconds. What I really want to know is if `nc` was able to succesfully connect to the host (exit status of 0).

To work around the `nc` issue, I've run `nc` thorugh the `timeout` command. This produces the desired functionality however timeout always exits with a 124 status code.

What I really want is the exit status of `nc`.  How can I get that when running 
`timeout 5 nc -w 5 bach; echo $?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `timeout` man page (GNU coreutils 8.22) ...

> --preserve-status
>        exit with the same status as COMMAND, even when the command times out

So your command would become

```
timeout --preserve-status 5 nc -w 5 bach; echo $?
```

However, I've just noticed that the original `nc` command uses the `-w` option which isn't what we want here. That tells `nc` to close the connection if it is idle *not* to give up if the connection takes too long.

The option we really want is `-G` which sets the TCP connection timeout. We want `-w` as well so that the connection will be closed (because we're not sending anything).

This gives a simple `nc` command of

```
nc -G 5 -w 5 bach; echo $?
```

Alternative approach is to just echo an empty line into `nc` to send to the server

```
echo | nc -G 5 bach; echo $?
```